# Is there a way to rewrite the hash character in a url - htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have a client who has gone ahead and setup a whole bunch of URLs which have gone into an app and I need to redirect to various pages in a cms based site.   They've used the following format: **url.co.nz/#media_2234**  which I need to rewrite to **url.co.nz/__media_2234** (or similar) before it gets to the cms, so I can deal with it properly (ie not treating it as an anchor)...so far I've tried a bunch of htaccess rewrites but none seem to work - this is the latest I've found - using the NE to not escape the hash:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
RewriteEngine On

# rewrite the media links    
RewriteRule ^#media_(.*)$ /__media$1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

Which also doesn't seem to work...any helpful suggestions?

Comment: The fragement portion of the URL does not even get send to the server, so No, you can not rewrite it from there.

Comment: Instead of rewriting on the server side you could implement a client side logic that reacts in the change of the location object when those anchors are used and then requests the desired resource from your CMS.